# Call Redirecting with Twilio

Tags: twilio, tracking, phone-call

I am very new with Twilio and call tracking services, but as Mongoose Metrics handles what I need but costs too much money so I am trying to switch Mongoose to another one but cheaper.

I am wondering if Twilio can replace Mongoose Metrics call tracking service.
What I really need is, I need to generate random phone numbers with my area code and those numbers need to redirect to my client business phone number.

The reason of call redirecting is when a customer actually dial the generated phone number, the call can redirect to my client business phone number so that Twilio can track those calls and record the calls.

So I need to make sure if Twilio can handle these below
1. Generated phone number can be redirected to another phone number
   (A user actually dials Twilio generated number from either landline or cell)
2. Record live phone calling
   (Conversation calling, not like voice message)

(This scenario is the only an example that my application needs to handle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

All of this is absolutely possible with Twilio. Here's a quick guide on [searching and buying Twilio numbers](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-use-the-api-to-search-for-and-buy-twilio-phone-numbers). Here's a guide for [redirecting Twilio numbers to your business number](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-set-up-call-forwarding). And finally a couple of words on how to [record conversations with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-record-a-phone-call-with-twilio).

You will need to do a bit of programming to tie all those bits together, but it is indeed all possible. Get started with phone numbers here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers

If you want to chat further about this, you could [get in touch with sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) or if you want to talk about development, drop me a line at philnash@twilio.com and I'd be glad to help!